# JTAppleCalendar delegate method is nil for specific project setup

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewdelegate, jtapplecalendar

I'm using [JTAppleCalendar](https://github.com/patchthecode/JTAppleCalendar) library in my app. Week ago I faced strange issue when `func calendar(_ calendar: JTAppleCalendarView, didSelectDate date: Date, cell: JTAppleCell?, cellState: CellState)` stoped working in App Store version but it was working in current dev branch.

After quick research I've found that only thing that changed was `FBSDKCoreKit` and `FBSDKLoginKit` cocoapods versions - `4.34.0`. So I decide to update their versions to `4.38.1` and it resolved an issue.

Unfortunatly I can reproduce this issue only in my project(which is comercial) that has other libraries, VIPER architecture and for obvious reasons I can't share it.

However I don't think that pods can lead to such issue, so I'm trying investigate what could cause such problem. After few hours I found that `delegate` of `UICollectionView` is nil and that's why `didSelectItemAt` is not responding.

I checked it simply by putting breakpoint after

```
super.dataSource = self
super.delegate = self
```

in `InternalActionFunctions.swift` file and `super.delegate` was `nil`.

[image]
In `JTAppleCalendarVariables.swift` file I've found that author made `delegate` and `dataSource` variables private with next code

```
@available(*, unavailable)
/// Will not be used by subclasses
open override var delegate: UICollectionViewDelegate? {
    get { return super.delegate }
    set { /* Do nothing */ }
}

@available(*, unavailable)
/// Will not be used by subclasses
open override var dataSource: UICollectionViewDataSource? {
    get { return super.dataSource }
    set {/* Do nothing */ }
}
```

Commenting this code resolves my issue, `delegate` has assigned value and everything works perfectly.

So my question is how above code can lead to such weird issues when in some cases `didSelectItemAt` method works and in others it doesn't? or maybe I'm on wrong way and it couldn't be a reason at all?

Comment: ever solved this?

Comment: @iOSCalendarpatchthecode.com yea, I fixed it. Weird, but a reason has been  `FBSDKCoreKit` pod of `4.34.0` version. After I updated it version to `4.38.0`, issue gone